# Unable to install JRebel on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jrebel

I'm trying to set up JRebel on my Eclipse Indigo but whatever I do I'm unable to install it correctly. Already installed it trough the Eclipse Marketplace, direct link, zip and nothing.

It doesn't give me any error during install, but after I restart Eclipse it simply doesn't show up the registration options.

I checked into the installed plugins (trough Eclipse's Plug-in registry) and the JRebel plugin is stopped. When I try to manually launch it, it always shows me the following error:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.fullversion=J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Vista amd64-64 jvmwa6460-20081105_25433 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20081105_025433_LEdSMr
JIT  - r9_20081031_1330
GC   - 20081027_AB
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Tue Nov 18 09:51:40 GMT 2014
The bundle "org.zeroturnaround.eclipse_6.0.0.RELEASE-201410311652 [1798]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty; bundle-version="0.0.0"

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.zeroturnaround.eclipse_6.0.0.RELEASE-201410311652 [1798]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty; bundle-version="0.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.registry.model.LocalRegistryBackend.start(LocalRegistryBackend.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.registry.model.Bundle.start(Bundle.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.runtime.registry.RegistryBrowser$12.run(RegistryBrowser.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Where am I supposed to download *"org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty; bundle-version=**0.0.0**"*?

Already lost more than one day trying how to make this work. Wasn't JRebel supposed to help increase our productivity? I've got 3 days to give my opinion if JRebel is an improvement to our 100+ development team, and if to install is such a big deal I wonder the rest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One user had similar issue, conversation visible [here](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-plugin-for-eclipse-not-visible-after-install/page/2/#post-42781) . Try these steps and if they don't work, it would be more simple and faster to just set up new Eclipse installation. If you do not wish to do that, contact support@zeroturnaround.com with link to this conversation, could try few other things.

Comment: I had already tried all of those suggestions with no success. I wanted to solve the problem in my current installation and workspace, to have a better comparison before and after JRebel.

Comment: I finally gave up and download a fresh Eclipse version, created a new workspace and it worked ok.